# DataGridView Column Formatting

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've been trying to force various columns in a DataGridView to take specified formats.

I've succeeded formatting my dates with the following:

```
dataToDoList.Columns["Due Date"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd MMMM yyyy";
```

However I cant seem to format other columns in which I only want to show times.
I've tried the following without success:

```
dataTimeSheet.Columns["Finish Time"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "hh:mm";
```

Has anyone any ideas what is wrong with this second line?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#". That's what tags are for.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Date time formatting is often rather odd. Take a look at [MSDN's article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) on it for some advice.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I modified my sql Command to get the info in the correct format at source

```
LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), te.StartTime, 8), 5) AS [Start Time], 
LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), te.FinishTime, 8), 5) AS [Finish Time]
```